# Find an integer x such that 1 < x < 2^32767 − 1 and 2^32767 − 1 is divisible by x (how to solve it intro)

Tags: proof-writing, problem-solving, word-problem

This is the second part to a question in the introductory proof book How to Solve It. In the first part I factored `2^15 - 1 = 32767` into 31(1057) and I found that using this xy = (2^b − 1) · (1 + 2^b + 2^2b + · · · + 2^(a−1)b ) , where xy = n and the n is from 2^n-1 which can possibly result in a prime number if n is prime, but will not equal a prime number if n is not prime.

the second question is this - Find an integer x such that 1 < x < 2^32767 − 1 and 2^32767 − 1 is divisible by x. I know that 32767 = 31(1057) and so either 31 or 1057 is greater than 1 and less than 2^32767-1, but I'm lost how to find the integer that divides into 2^32767-1 and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the same logic.  You have identified that $2^a-1|2^{ab}-1$, so use your factorization of $32767=31\cdot 1057$ to say that $2^{32767}-1$ is divisible by $2^{31}-1$ or $2^{1057}-1$.  In fact $1057=7\cdot 151$ so you have a couple other factors available as well.

Comment: How did you find that 2^31-1 or 2^1057-1 can divide into 2^32767-1 from that?

Comment: From the first line, which I took from your post.  The more general statement is that $(c-d)|(c^n-d^n)$  I applied that with $c=2^{31},d=1,n=1057$  It also justifies the statement that $2^n-1$ cannot be prime unless $n$ is

Comment: Alright, I'm not sure how you got the general statement (c-d)(c^n - d^n) from that, but I looked back at the  (2^b-1)(1 + 2^b+2^2b+...+2^(a-1)b) = 2^n-1 and realized I could just take one part of this and it would be divisible to 2^n-1 so the answer could also be 1 + 2^31... a 1057 times to 2^(1057-1)31. Thanks a lot for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You missed the divides sign in your comment.  Maybe it was just a typo.  I answered a question years ago proving this, but I can't find it now.